# Why can an interface not simply be added to a bridge?

Tags: routing, bridge

My mental model of Linux' bridge is wrong.

I have always considered a bridge similar to a simple, unmanaged switch: You plug in some ethernet cables, and data is then copied from one port to another based on the MAC addresses that communicate on that port. In particular: The switch itself does *not* have an IP-address.

So I had expected that I could simply do:

```
brctl addbr mybr
brctl addif mybr eth0
```

with eth0 having an IP-address.

But I cannot get that to work: Any IP-addresses associaled with eth0 seem to be ignored.

Instead I can do:

```
    default_interface=$(ip -4 route ls | grep default | grep -Po '(?<=dev )(\S+)')
    dif=$default_interface
    gw=$(ip -4 route ls | grep default | grep -Po '(?<=via )(\S+)')
    dif_ip=$(ip -4 route ls | grep default | grep -Po '(?<=src )(\S+)')
    echo Add bridge
    sudo brctl addbr mybr
    # $dif must be up, but with no ip addr
    sudo ip addr flush dev $dif
    sudo brctl addif mybr $dif
    sudo ifconfig mybr $dif_ip
    sudo route add -net 0.0.0.0 gw $gw
```

This moves the IP address and routing from eth0 to the bridge.

I understand *that* I cannot simply do: `brctl addif eth0` what I do not understand is *why*.

Comment: Does the combination of _"The switch itself does not have an IP-address"_ and _"...`brctl addif mybr eth0` with eth0 having an IP-address"_ mean that you see `addif` as a way to connect `eth0` to a bridge device using a (sort of) piece of cable? Or just that the device's IP configuration could become that of the bridge when the former is added to the latter?

Comment: @fra-san In my mental model `addif` plugs the "cable" into the switch.

Comment: In my view, `addif` makes an interface "disappear" in IP terms, making it part of the bridge itself, while the Linux optional feature of assigning IP addresses to bridge devices conveniently allows the host to still be reached on the network even if it has no non-bridged interfaces. I don't feel knowledgeable enough to post an answer, though.

Comment: addif doesn't plug the cable. It inserts the interface as bridge port: it's no more independent but as written it became a slave of the bridge. Maybe you have a real problem to solve? Usually: move the address from the interface to the bridge without losing connectivity.